# how to show progress bar in struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I need to show a progress bar or waiting page using struts2, waiting page works but once it shows the wait page it does not redirects to success page although the process is completed and results are ready to be shown (I've figure it out using System.out.println)

```
<interceptors>
<interceptor name="AuthenticationInterceptor" 
            class="com.funontour.interceptors.AuthenticationInterceptor"/>

     <interceptor-stack name="secureStack">
       <interceptor-ref name="AuthenticationInterceptor"/>
           <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
     </interceptor-stack>

     <interceptor-stack name="waitStack">
       <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
           <interceptor-ref name="execAndWait"/>
      </interceptor-stack>

   </interceptors>


<action name="Process" class="application.processAction" method="Process">
    <interceptor-ref name="waitStack"/>
    <result name="SUCCESS" type="tiles">SuccessPage</result>
    <result name="wait" type="tiles">waitPage</result>
</action>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you updating your page with javascript or with `http-equiv="refresh"`?
See http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/execute-and-wait-interceptor.html for examples.